# How to use a form to cycle through php array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

so my basic array code is below. I'm wanting to have a "next" button that will basically display one result at a time on the same page. So when pressed it would replace the current testimonial on the page.  Not really sure how to do this with the array being in php. basically just want it to reload and increment the `$current`. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
$testercount = count($testimonials);
$current = 0;
if ($current <= $testercount){
       $t = $testimonials[$current];
    $t['text'] = str_replace("\n", '<br/>', $t['text']);
    $t['text'] = str_replace(chr(146), '\'', $t['text']);
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<p>'.$t['text'].'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.$t['name'].'</p>';
    echo '<hr/></div>';

}
```

Comment: what will your target php version be?

Comment: so did the code below worked out for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

```
<?php
session_start();

$testercount = count($testimonials);
$current = 0;
if (isset($_SESSION['current_counter'])) $current = $_SESSION['current_counter']+1; //increment here..
$_SESSION['current_counter'] = $current;

if ($current <= $testercount){
    $t = $testimonials[$current];
    $t['text'] = str_replace("\n", '<br/>', $t['text']);
    $t['text'] = str_replace(chr(146), '\'', $t['text']);
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<p>'.$t['text'].'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.$t['name'].'</p>';
    echo '<hr/></div>';
}
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body><form method="get" target="#"><input type="submit" value="Next" /></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but how do i use a button to let the user increment through them with that method?

Comment: by adding a form and submitting, or a link to the page. See updated code

Comment: awesome thanks!  is there a way to do it where the whole page doesn't reload but just the text changes?

Comment: using ajax and a bit of javascript, you can easily achieve it.